# findOneAndUpdate of MongoDB delete data regardless of $set on pre hook

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

There are documents in mongodb as below.

```
[{
    _id: "x8",
    company: {
        name: "ms",
        number: 123,
    },
    position: "12.12"
}]
```

And I update this using pre hook of mongoose with nestjs.

```
  schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function () {
      this.set({
          company: {name: "X3jfks"} // encrypt Field in pre hook.
      });
   });
```

And there is a findOneAndUpdate Method.

```
const updateData = {
    company: "xyz"
}

await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: "x8"},
    ...updateData
)
```

But the document is changed differently from my intention as below.
That is, company.number is disappeared.

```
[{
    company: {
        name: "X3jfks",
    },
    position: "12.12"
}]
```

I need this result.

```
[{
    company: {
        name: "X3jfks",
        number: 123,
    },
    position: "12.12"
}]
```

But the result is same with $set.

```
await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: "x8"},
    {$set: {...updateData}}
)
```

I have to use this.set() inside of pre hook. Is there some solution for this problem? Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Please change you hook, Currently it updates whole company object because you have assigned new value to company field. Instead of assigning new value to complete field you need to update only the key of company object.

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function () {
  this.set({
      "company.name":"X3jfks" // encrypt Field in pre hook.
  });
});
```

Comment: Pushpendra Singh How can I make complete field inside of pre-hook?